# Running "Runtime.getRuntime().exec()" in a loop

Tags: android, kotlin

Like the title, I want to run a "Runtime.getRunTime().exec()" command in a while loop. Currently, it only executes once (other objects in the while loop are executed multiple times). I've tried destroying the process but doesn't work. Example below:

```
var x  = 0

val P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    arrayOf(
        "su", "-c", "" +
        "monkey -p com.ubercab -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1"
    )
)

while (x < 10) {

    Log.i("app", x.toString())
    P.waitFor()
    x += 1    

}
```

In the code above the Log statement is repeated but the P.waitFor() is only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `exec` will be executed only once, and its result will be stored in the `P` variable. Calling `waitFor` on this repeatedly won't execute it again, it just reads the same result over and over.

You could wrap the call in a lambda, and call that lambda in a loop to execute it multiple times:

```
val P: () -> Process = {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            arrayOf(
                    "su", "-c", "" +
                    "monkey -p com.ubercab -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1"
            )
    )
}

while (x < 10) {
    Log.i("app", x.toString())
    P().waitFor()
    x += 1
}
```

Or you could place it in a regular function:

```
fun p(): Process {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            arrayOf(
                    "su", "-c", "" +
                    "monkey -p com.ubercab -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1"
            )
    )
}

while (x < 10) {
    Log.i("app", x.toString())
    p().waitFor()
    x += 1
}
```

Comment: Oh, I understand!!! It'd be like declaring var currentTimestamp = [getting current timestamp] and then calling that variable over and over. I have to put it in a function instead.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it!